# Is it possible with chef 'include_recipe ' to append cookbook version?

Tags: chef-infra, recipe

i know we can include version when we run cookbook like

```
    chef-client -o "recipe[mycookbook@0.1.1]"
```

How can version can be appended when doing include_recipe

```
    include_recipe "apache2::mod_ssl"@version?
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't possible using `include_recipe` in the Chef Recipe DSL. Your options for supplying a particular version are using:

- the runlist in a role or on a node, e.g. `"recipe[mycookbook@0.1.1]"`
- an environment pinning a cookbook, e.g.:

  cookbook_versions({
      "nginx" => "<= 1.1.0",
      "apt" => "= 0.0.1"
  })
- the metadata.rb file in a cookbook, e.g. `depends 'apt', '1.2.3'`.

Since you're looking to pin a version from within a cookbook, why not declare it in `metadata.rb`? That will have a direct effect on the `include_recipe` statement you're using, forcing that include to use the version declared in your metadata.

In your example, that would be:

```
depends 'mycookbook, '0.1.1'
```

Or to use the apache example, in your `metadata.rb` file:

```
depends 'apache2', 'version'
```

And then in your recipe:

```
include_recipe "apache2::mod_ssl"
```